# Dedicated server in the cloud as media server with Raspberry Pi at home

Tags: server, mediaserver, raspberrypi

I have an hosted server on OVH, it's running my small website, owncloud to backup my photos, and a lot of mp4/h264 and avi/xvid.
I would like to use it as a media server to stream video to my raspberry Pi which is connected to my PC.
Now I'm not sure about the approach I should have. The ubuntu server can stream h264 videos to a web browser, as I have install the appropriate apache mod. Should the server simply share the videos as files, or should it stream, and in this case, what should I use on the PI to open the stream ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: UPDATE: as this question is quite popular it seems, I'll share my solution.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one options but i would advise for [Plex](http://www.plexapp.com/)

i am using it for same purpose and it can smoothly stream your videos music etc to all devices.

Edit:
What i am suggesting you is to install plex on your linux/ubuntu server and than you can install xmbc or any other Media client on Raspberry pi. Plex also supports streaming for xmbc. but best part is you can use streaming for plex even on your IOS or android based devices.
and also it publishes your server to my.plex which allows you to access it securely from outside as well.

Comment: Including the raspberry Pi ?

Comment: Plex has recently launched a beta version for Raspberry Pi but it's in early stage according to them a release is 2-3 months away.

Comment: But what i suggest you was to install plex on your linux/ubuntu server and than you can install xmbc or any other Media client on Raspberry pi. Plex also supports streaming for xmbc. but best part is you can use streaming for plex even on your IOS or android based devices.

Comment: With the 17$ app ? Or is there any free version ?

Comment: Server is free and can be downloaded from http://plexapp.com/getplex/index.php which you can install on your linux host.

Comment: Plex server is installed and running - had some issues in the process, but running ok now. The iPhone app would still be 3 USD though.

Answer (score 0):

Plex client does not work on a Raspberry PI, make the media share on your Ubuntu server a SMB or NFS share, install XBMC on the Raspberry PI and mount the media share on it and point XBMC to it.

Comment: That's interesting because Usman and yourself are mentioning the two possible approaches I had in mind. Isn't a SMB or NFS share less secured though ? I don't have a static IP address at home.